# How to merge to same dataframe multiple times without the _x and _y suffixes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
print(df1)

   id     match
0   1     hello
1   2     there
2   3       NaN
3   4     stack
4   5       NaN
5   6  overflow
6   7       NaN
7   8        hi
8   9       NaN

print(df2)

   id match
0   1   NaN
1   2   NaN
2   3   put
3   4   NaN
4   5   new
5   6   NaN
6   7  data
7   8   NaN
8   9   NaN
```

I would like to fill the `Nan` in df1 with values from df2. 
You can see they share the same `id` numbers. 
`id 3` in `df1` is `Nan`, but I have a value for it in `df2` which is the word `put`.

So I would like to fill in the missing values where possible by merging:

```
df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='id')

   id   match_x match_y
0   1     hello     NaN
1   2     there     NaN
2   3       NaN     put
3   4     stack     NaN
4   5       NaN     new
5   6  overflow     NaN
6   7       NaN    data
7   8        hi     NaN
8   9       NaN     NaN
```

You can see I am getting the `_x` and `_y` suffixes.

I have tried inner and outer merging also and the suffixes are still there.

My expected output. You can see that most of the data was filled in.

```
   id     match
0   1     hello
1   2     there
2   3       put
3   4     stack
4   5       new
5   6  overflow
6   7      data
7   8        hi
8   9       NaN
```

After this I would like to get a `df3` which will have the value for `id 9`, then merge that to df1 also, etc etc.

Basically I would like to continuously update the `match` column in df1 with new values from other dataframes, based on 'id'.

Is it possible with pandas `merge` without adding the `_x , _y` suffixes?

My dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=9, step=1)), 'match': pd.Series(['hello', 'there', nan, 'stack', nan, 'overflow', nan, 'hi', nan],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=9, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=9, step=1))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=9, step=1)), 'match': pd.Series([nan, nan, 'put', nan, 'new', nan, 'data', nan, nan],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=9, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=9, step=1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Series.fillna` with `DataFrame.set_index`

```
df1['match'] = (
    df1.set_index('id')['match'].fillna(df2.set_index('id')['match']).reset_index(drop=True)
)
df3 = df1.copy()
```

```
   id     match
0   1     hello
1   2     there
2   3       put
3   4     stack
4   5       new
5   6  overflow
6   7      data
7   8        hi
8   9       NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is `concat` with `groupby+first`:

```
pd.concat((df1,df2)).groupby('id').first().reset_index()
```

---

```
   id     match
0   1     hello
1   2     there
2   3       put
3   4     stack
4   5       new
5   6  overflow
6   7      data
7   8        hi
8   9       NaN
```

Comment: Nice solution here:)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,

we can set index by `id` and use combine first :

```
new_df = df1.set_index('id').combine_first(df2.set_index('id'))
```

---

```
print(new_df)

       match
id          
1      hello
2      there
3        put
4      stack
5        new
6   overflow
7       data
8         hi
9        NaN
```

#### Using Map.

if you are just filling NaN values you can use `map` across a common key.

```
df1["match"] = df1["match"].fillna(df1["id"].map(df2.set_index("id")["match"]))

print(df1)

   id     match
0   1     hello
1   2     there
2   3       put
3   4     stack
4   5       new
5   6  overflow
6   7      data
7   8        hi
8   9       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's different from my expected output. Now there are two `match` columns with this solution.

Comment: sorry totally missed the output! @SCool

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), assuming everything is sorted correctly in the index.

`df1.combine_first(df2)`

if not then you need to merge on index
`df1.set_index('id').combine_first(df2.set_index('id'))`

```
   id     match
0   1     hello
1   2     there
2   3       put
3   4     stack
4   5       new
5   6  overflow
6   7      data
7   8        hi
8   9       NaN
```

Comment: This only works because the indices are alligned correctly in this example. `id` should be the index here

Comment: I assumed they would be, added the index solution

Comment: "assuming everything is sorted correctly" is still wrong, it's not about sorting, `combine_first` alligns on index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataFrame.merge` + [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
df1[['id']].merge(df2,on = 'id',how = 'left').fillna({'match':df1['match']})

   id     match
0   1     hello
1   2     there
2   3       put
3   4     stack
4   5       new
5   6  overflow
6   7      data
7   8        hi
8   9       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `update`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
​df2 = df2.set_index('id')
​df1.update(df2)
​df1
```

Output:

```
       match
id          
1      hello
2      there
3        put
4      stack
5        new
6   overflow
7       data
8         hi
9        NaN
```

Comment: What if I have many more columns other than `match` ? How to target that column only for the update?

Comment: It will match on index and column header.  Almost all operations in pandas are aligned using indexes, both row and column.  To prove it to yourself, simply create a small test case.,

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.update(df2, join='left')
```

> Modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.
>   Aligns on indices. There is no return value.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update

oh my bad I didn't reload to see Scott's answer